# AWS: error while creating AMI from Ubuntu - error initramfs/initrd

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, import, ubuntu-20.04, amazon-ami

I've created a simple VM in VirtualBox and installed Ubuntu, however, I am unable to import this to AWS and generate an AMI from it.
Operating system: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-104-generic

I've followed the steps provided according to the docs and setup role-policy.json & trust-policy.json:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmie_prereqs.html#vmimport-role

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmimport-image-import.html

I keep running into the error:

```
{
    "ImportImageTasks": [
        {
            "Description": "My server VM",
            "ImportTaskId": "import-ami-xxx",
            "SnapshotDetails": [
                {
                    "DeviceName": "/dev/sde",
                    "DiskImageSize": 2362320896.0,
                    "Format": "VMDK",
                    "Status": "completed",
                    "Url": "s3://xxxx/simple-vm.ova",
                    "UserBucket": {
                        "S3Bucket": "xxx",
                        "S3Key": "simple-vm.ova"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "Status": "deleted",
            "StatusMessage": "ClientError: We were unable to read your import's initramfs/initrd to determine what drivers your import requires to run in EC2.",
            "Tags": []
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried changing disk to and from .vdi and .vmdk

I've tried disabling floppy drive and update initramfs

Comment: I am not sure whether you're using Vagrant in combination with VirtualBox, I assume not since you didn't mention Vagrant.

I was able to work around this issue by using Vagrant and instead of using the 
**ubuntu/focal64**, I used the **geerlingguy/ubuntu2004** image and it imported perfectly without any issues.

Just remember to remove the default vagrant credentials of vagrant/vagrant.

Comment: any fix for this?

Comment: I didn't want to re-ask this question so I offered a bounty, wondering if you got around it or noticed that you used "VMDK" as the Format to import an OVA (OVA is a valid format name).  I'm trying the same thing with a RAW disk image created with QEMU.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error and was able to get around it by using [import-snapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmimport-import-snapshot.html) instead of import-image.  Then I could deploy the snapshot using the ordinary means of [creating an image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/backup-recovery/restore.html) from the snapshot.